# Plusquamperfekt und Konjunktiv II

Tags: subjunctive, pluperfect

> Wenn ich mehr Bier getrunken gehabt hätte, hätte ich meine Wohnung nicht gefunden.

Ist das so richtig ?

Wenn nicht: Wie benutzt man das Plusquamperfekt mit dem Konjunktiv II?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plusquamperfekt, Indikativ:

> Gabi sah mir gestern Abend tief in die Augen, aber davor **hatte** ich ziemlich viel Bier **getrunken,** daher bemerkte ich es nicht.
>
> Gabi looked deeply into my eyes yesterday evening, but before that I had drunk a lot of beer, so I did not notice it.

You use Plusquamperfekt only for actions, that happened before another event in the past. So you always need two different actions. In my example the reference point in the past is the moment when Gabi looked into my eyes. You use Präteritum to describe this action. Sometimes you also can use Perfekt.

The event, that happened before this reference point, is drinking beer, and so you have to use Plusquamperfekt.

But all I said before, is for Indikativ, which is used for facts that really happened.

Konjunktiv II is used if you wish or imagine something that is irreal:

> Gabi sah mir gestern Abend tief in die Augen, aber wenn ich davor ziemlich viel Bier **getrunken hätte,** hätte ich es nicht bemerkt.

In your example, this would be correct:

> Wenn ich (vor der Suche) mehr Bier **getrunken hätte,** hätte ich meine Wohnung nicht gefunden.
>
> If I had drunk more beer (before the search), I would not have found my apartment.

Comment: Also, es gibt im Konjunktiv II nur zwei Zeitformen: Gegenwart und Vergangenheit ...es gibt kein Plusquamperfekt

Comment: @MikeAshi In manchen süddeutschen Dialekten gibt es durchaus ein Perfekt im Konjunktiv. "Wann i mera Bia drunga ghabt hätt".

Comment: Warum ist denn die Antwort auf Englisch geschrieben? Die Frage ist doch in klarem Deutsch gestellt.

Comment: Irgenwie habe ich den Eindruck, dass die Frage nicht beantwortet wurde. Statt dessen wird ein neues Beispiel erfunden und das wird dann erklärt. Ist der Originalsatz nun richtig oder nicht? In meinen Augen ist er richtig, auch wenn er sich von dem Satz unterscheidet, den die Frage beantwortet.